# How to get index of all the same elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I get index of all the places where the same element is present. I have been using the index() method, but I only get the index of the first apperance of that element.

```
print([1, 1, 2, 3].index(1))
```

I need both an output of both 0 and 1. My knowlegde about coding terms is very bad sorry, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
print([i for i, x in enumerate([1, 1, 2, 3]) if x==1])
[0, 1]
```